# strange behavior: apparently a numpy nan in a pandas dataframe showing up as dtype('float64')

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am working on a dataframe that has many custom functions, libraries, and calculations. After doing some critical calcs, I noticed some errors in calculations that should have returned a float:

[image]

To inspect one of the calculations, I do the following.

```
dFA.loc['20101120']['variable x']
```

which returns (**in small caps**)

```
nan
```

Then, to confirm that this thing is what looks like a weird (small caps) numpy.nan (**True** or **False**) I do:

```
dFA.loc['20101120']['variable x'] == np.nan
```

Which returns:

```
False
```

Then I do:

```
dFA.loc['20101120']['variable x'].dtype
```

Which returns:

```
dtype('float64')
```

Also:

```
dFA.loc['20101120']['variable x'] > 1000
False
```

Also:

```
dFA.loc['20101120']['variable x'] < 1000
False
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> dFA.loc['20101120']['variable x'] == np.nan
> ```

Oops. NaN is never equal to NaN.

```
np.isnan(dFA.loc['20101120']['variable x'])
```

Comment: What do you mean NaN is never equal to NaN? Why is this nan showing up as float64?

Comment: I mean exactly what I said; performing an equality comparison between two NaNs will always result in false. NaNs are just floats with specific bit sequences.

Answer (score 2):

All comparisons with `np.nan` evaluate to `False` by [definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565164/what-is-the-rationale-for-all-comparisons-returning-false-for-ieee754-nan-values).

```
>>> np.nan == np.nan
False
>>> np.nan <= 1
False
>>> np.nan > 1
False
```

`np.nan` *is* a float:

```
>>> np.nan.__class__
<type 'float'>
```

... just a very special one.